# Auto adjust columns when menu is shown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was trying to implement a left -side bar menu like [shown here](http://themes-lab.com/preview/?theme=Pixit%20Admin) using the standard Bootstrap 3, however I only managed to get the rest of the columns out of the screen.

have a look at the example like this:
When the menu is collapsed:

[image]

When its expanded this is what happens:
[image]

the bootstrap example is [here](http://www.bootply.com/render/96266)

Is there a way I can prevent the screen from moving out of the view?

Regards
Kiran

Comment: Can you please show us you're html and any custom css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.row-offcanvas {
position: relative;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

Change the above `position:relative` to `position:absolute`

That will prevent the left bar pushing the main content out of view, the main content will shrink responsivly instead. However, you will need to adjust some styling to your expanded left-side bar as you will see (not too much though).

Edit: line 297